# How is it that on loading a spring, shearing stress is produced?

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

As far as I know, shearing stress is produced when layers shift parallel to each other, which means there is change in shape, and the layers are displaced in the direction of force applied. I imagine shearing strain as, say, the way a deck of cards changes its shape when you apply force on the topmost cards.

But in a spring, on applying force, it stretches, thereby producing longitudinal strain, and its width decreases, producing lateral strain. How come does it produce shearing strain? No layer is sliding on top of another.

[image: shearing stress]

Comment: do you mean a helicoidal spring? If so, the answer is in the shape: the center line of the "quasi-1d" material is turning around the axis, aligned with the direction of the load

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of part of a spring which is subjected to forces $W$.

[image]

The cross-section $A$ of the spring is subjected to a torsion, shearing force over area $A$, which makes produces a twisting of the spring and that twisting is the main cause of the extension of a spring when under load.
There is also a vertical shear which contributes to the extension of the spring.

$\dfrac{\text{extension due to vertical shear}}{\text{extension due to torsion}} \approx \dfrac{\text{radius of wire}^2}{\text{2 radius of spring}^2}$ which usually means that the effect of torsion is dominant.